# How can I query documents where a property matches an item in a list (c# driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Person class with a PersonID (int) property. I need to pull out all people whose PersonID is contained in a List (i.e. I have 5,000,000 people in the collection, but I need to only grab the people whose ID is in the list (typically 10 or 20 - sometimes more, sometimes less).

How can I do this with the c# driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, I don't have full structure of Person class, I'll be using generic BsonDocument for query. Your best bet is usage of `$in` or [In operator](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.2/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_In__1_1.htm)

Try:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("database");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");
```

Note that I'm passing list of Ids to `Filter.In` operator in next line.

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("PersonID", new List<int>() {0,1,2,3});
var result = collection.FindSync(filter).ToList();
```

Result should hold all person who's Id is in range `0,1,2,3`

Answer (score 0):

Try

list.Where(x => x.PersonID == MyPerson.ID)

You'll need to add a reference to System.Linq in order to use this syntax. Basically, what this means is "I'm going though all the objects in my collection, lets call each one "x", and I'm going to check each objects PersonID property against my own value." These Lambda expressions can be very helpful in streamlining code!